# Reasonable values of the constants in Hick's Law

Tags: menu

In reading about Hick's Law, I keep finding statements such as

> The Hick-Hyman Law, then, states that the time T to
> choose an item is proportional to its information content,
> giving T=a+b×H, where a and b are empirically derived
> constants.

http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/andrew.cockburn/papers/paper191-cockburn.pdf

I have yet to find what the measured values of the constants are.  I'm sure they change depending on the context, but are there reasonable values one can assume when trying to predict reaction times in contexts where no data about their values is available?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

> the constants a and b depend heavily on the exact task setting and input device, so be wary of substituting "typical" values for these constants, or of comparing constants derived from different studies. [[HCI Fundamentals, p.142](https://books.google.de/books?id=npLEMUzgQ_0C&lpg=PA142&ots=VHk6tR2jFo&dq=constants%20for%20hicks%20law&hl=de&pg=PA142#v=snippet&q=Fitts%27%20Law%20and%20Hick%27s%20law&f=false)]

But in a lecture about HCI, I've also learned that when applying Hick's Law in a scenario where the user can search by sub-division, at least *a common practical value for b is 150ms*. The lecture refers to [usabilityfirst.com/glossary/hicks-law](http://usabilityfirst.com/glossary/hicks-law). This constant b is the processing speed.

The constant a usually is the total time that is not involved in decision making. In my opinion this is where you should pay more attention to the above warning, as it could heavily vary. While having a quick research I've found this little example:

> For example, assume it takes 2 seconds to detect an alarm and understand it's meaning. Further, assume that pressing one of five buttons will solve the problem caused by the alarm. The time to respond would be RT = (2 sec) + (0.155 sec)(log²(5)) = 2.36 sec. [[jedbrubaker.com](http://www.jedbrubaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Day7-HicksLaw.pdf)]

I very much doubt that the two seconds will also fit your scenario, so my advice would be to make your own careful assumption for the constant a in your scenario.